# SQL Server sp_addrolemember in stored procedure for different database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I have a stored procedure to restore the latest backup of a prod database to an acceptance database. Once it's restored I need to grant a user read access to the database.

Use statements are not allowed in stored procedures, and both `ALTER ROLE` (it's a SQL Server 2012 box) and `sp_addrolemember` don't take a target database parameter.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EXEC('USE mydb;ALTER ROLE myRole ADD MEMBER myMember;');
```

But I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. After restoring a database to a different server, you need to fix the link between users and logins. For that you can execute this in your database:

```
ALTER USER myUser WITH LOGIN myLogin;
```

Or use the same `EXEC('USE...')` method shown above with that `ALTER USER` statement. That should get you where you need to be. All the database related permissions are stored in the database itself, so they get restored with the database.

Comment: I need to grant access to the restored database for a user that does not have access to the original database.